# How To know which Child content page is getting called from in MasterPage

Tags: asp.net

I am wondering if there is a way to tell what page master page is getting run from: 
For example if the default.aspx is the first page to load and then it goes to master page is there a way to know within Master Page that the child was Default.aspx?

What I am trying to do is when a client gets onto the page "Default.aspx" and they click on the tree view selection to automatically take them "Home Page" but if they click on the tree view selection again within "Home Page" to stay within "Home Page" so only redirect once when you make first selection within Default.aspx.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: title misleads many users, try to give descriptive title , so that rate of getting help will increase

Comment: Thanks... I just did not know the best title :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MasterPage class has a Page property which has URL-manipulation methods you could use to figure it out. But I get a whiff of code-smell thinking about a master page caring about which page is using it...

Comment: Check my updated post maybe you can get more understanding of what I am trying to do. Thank for your response.

Comment: But that means the master-page has to 'know' special things about the pages that use it. I think you're better off having your pages communicate with the master page to enable/disable links as they see fit

Comment: Well the "Home" page will contain list of data based on selection made on tree view. So they can change their tree view selection at anytime while being in the Home Page and the page should just be refreshed within home page displaying different data. But when they first open the page they are within "Welcome Page" so when they make their first selection it will redirect them to "Home Page"

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the Master Page Page_Load method:

```
String ChildPage;

ChildPage = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.FilePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Default.aspx is a page, this means it contains master page and content. If you want to transfer info between content page and master, you may proced something like this:

Build a custom MasterPage (A masterPage that inherit the MasterPage)

```
public class MyMasterPage : MasterPage {
//methods, properties, etc

    public string MyInfo {get; set;}
    }

}
```

and in content page you mai call this property like this:

```
((MyMasterPage)Page.masterPage).MyInfo = "default.aspx"
```